# Markov chain weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, weak-convergence

consider a sequence of Markov chains $\Phi^{(n)}$whose transition kernel $P^{(n)}$ converges to $P$. Now let $\Phi$ be the Markov chain with the limiting kernel $P$. How do I show that $\Phi^{(n)}\to \Phi$ weakly.

Comment: The answer to your question will refer to the theorem and Lemma of Karr >>> http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF00539859.pdf

Comment: @user17523 What is your state space? Is your time parameter discrete or continuous?

Comment: time is discrete, state space is uncountable.....also we know that each of the $\Phi^{(n)}$ are positive Harris recurrent